# Chrome Devtools: Accessing values in the summary of the network tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am running performance tests on a webpage and I noticed the network tab of Chrome DevTools has a summary bar at the bottom with number of requests, bytes transferred and finish time. I would like to console.log (or even better log to a file) these values at the end of each test.

I do see a chrome.loadTimes() which has the timing info. Is there something similar to retrieve number of requests and bytes transferred?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Resource Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resource_Timing_API/Using_the_Resource_Timing_API). It can give you a whole bunch of info on every resource that a page requests. And it's got [good cross-browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=resource-timing), so you can use it to collect some Real User Metrics on your page's load performance in the wild.